# Repeat Retrofit2 request using repeatWhen RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm working with `rxjava2`.
My problem is that sometimes server sends me nothing (response body is null, and so on List size = 0), so in that case I'd like to repeat request after 5 sec.
I have an `Retrofit2` request:

```
  @GET("/ics/api/{bidId}/calltracking/reports/widgets")
    Single<List<CallTrackingWidget>> getWidgets(@Path("bidId") int bidId);
```

Use it like so:

```
RetrofitFactory.getRetrofitService().getWidgets(mDataManager.getBidId())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(widgets -> getView().showLoading())
                .doOnSuccess(widgets -> getView().hideLoading())
                .repeatWhen(widgets -> widgets.flatMap(size -> {
                    if ((int) size == 0) {
                        return Flowable.just("asd").delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } else {
                        return widgets;
                    }
                }))
                .subscribe(widgets -> {
                    mDataManager.getProduct().getCallTrackingData().setWidgets(widgets);
                    getView().initWidgets(mDataManager.getProduct().getCallTrackingData().getWidgetNames());
                }, throwable -> {
                    handleError(throwable, R.string.error_internet);
                })
```

But my code a have an exeption:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: 
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Help me please  to repeat request after 5 sec, when List size is 0.

Comment: Aren't you updating or dealing with UI off the main thread? That `getView()` tells me you probably are. You can only work with the UI using the main thread, in Android.

Comment: The `delay()` operator will use `Schedulers.computation()` as its default scheduler. The `repeatWhen()` will then move the whole observer chain on to a computation thread and out of the main thread.

Comment: @BobDalgleish so how to solve it?

Comment: Move the `repeatWhen()` operator up the chain so it occurs before `observeOn()`. Anything downstream of `observeOn()` will continue to operate on the main thread, and upstream may change as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in these two lines:

```
.doOnSubscribe(widgets -> getView().showLoading())
.doOnSuccess(widgets -> getView().hideLoading())
```

These two actions will execute off the Main thread. And as the exception implies, you can only touch Android views from the Main thread.

Try moving this view manipulation somewhere else. Like this:

```
getView().showLoading(); // Show loading view
RetrofitFactory.getRetrofitService().getWidgets(mDataManager.getBidId())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .repeatWhen(widgets - > widgets.flatMap(size - > {
        if ((int) size == 0) {
            return Flowable.just("asd").delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } else {
            return widgets;
        }
    }))
    .subscribe(widgets - > {
        getView().hideLoading(); // Hide loading view
        mDataManager.getProduct().getCallTrackingData().setWidgets(widgets);
        getView().initWidgets(mDataManager.getProduct().getCallTrackingData().getWidgetNames());
    }, throwable - > {
        getView().hideLoading(); // Hide loading view
        handleError(throwable, R.string.error_internet);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't deal with the view on main thread, you can write like this:

```
RetrofitFactory.getRetrofitService().getWidgets(mDataManager.getBidId())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnSubscribe(widgets -> getView().showLoading())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .repeatWhen(widgets - > widgets.flatMap(size - > {
        if ((int) size == 0) {
            return Flowable.just("asd").delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } else {
            return widgets;
        }
    }))
    .subscribe(widgets - > {
        getView().hideLoading(); // Hide loading view
        mDataManager.getProduct().getCallTrackingData().setWidgets(widgets);
        getView().initWidgets(mDataManager.getProduct().getCallTrackingData().getWidgetNames());
    }, throwable - > {
        getView().hideLoading(); // Hide loading view
        handleError(throwable, R.string.error_internet);
    })
```